# Disposed Error when using await, .Result is working

Tags: c#

I have a async function, that is first calling a DbContext. If I'm using now the await function, I always get the **ObjectDisposedException**.

But if I'm using the the method .Result, I got the correct result. But i heard, that i should not use the method .Result, because it blocks until the Task is finished.

Code Example of my Code that got the ObjectDisposedException:

```cs
public async void AggrigateData()
{
    // some code
    var machineEvents = await _eventService.GetAllErrorEventsAsync();  // does not work
    var machineEvents = _eventService.GetAllErrorEventsAsync().Result; // does work
    var differentEventIds = machineEvents.Labels.Count; // Using machineEvents right after getting the result.
    // some code
}
```

So, what could I do, that this will work? Is it any problem here to use Result? Because I right away use the result of the _eventService.GetAllErrorEventsAsync() to count the Labels.

Thanks for your help.

**Addition (19.10.2022 17:04)**

The Function AggregateData is Used by an Event Handler. There I can't use an *async Task* because the Timer do not allow me to use it. I could change the DoWork to *async void* but then we have the same just one Function later.

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{            
    _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private void DoWork(object state)
{
    machineEvaluationService.AggrigateData()
}
```

**Solution**

First of all, thank all of you for your help. I appreciate that

I still do not definitly understand why this is working now but i changed my code above to this.

```cs
// I have a IHostedService (StartAsync) and in it, there is running a timer,
// that is doing some Work from the DoWork function. The Problem is, that
// the Timer dont accept any async Method. So it stays still the same as above.
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
        TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

// But I changed now my DoWork method to a async void Method. Now i can
// await for the machineEvaluationService Method AggregateDate().
private async void DoWork(object state)
{
    await machineEvaluationService.AggregateData();
}

// This is now finally working
public async Task AggrigateData()
{
    // some code
    var machineEvents = await _eventService.GetAllErrorEventsAsync();  
    var differentEventIds = machineEvents.Labels.Count; 
    // some code
}
```

Probably somebody have an explanation why it works when i use `async void` further outside. Otherwise I have to live with it.

Comment: `async void` should not be used unless absolutely necessary (because you need a fire-and-forget event handler and the signature must be `void`), otherwise, always prefer `async Task`. As the error suggests, `_eventService` (or something that it uses) is getting disposed before the method has a chance to actually do what it needs to do. To fix this you have to look at your other code -- why isn't it waiting anywhere for `AggregateData` to finish?

Comment: Change `async void` to `async Task` and *await* the method as well

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you, because I use an Event Handler (See my Addition), I have to use void. So do you think it is a Problem there to use Result in this Situation?

Comment: @RafaelEberle Is the method `AggregateData()` used **by** an event handler or **as** an event handler? In the first case, you can make the event handler `async void` and turn your method into `async Task AggregateData()` and await that inside of the event handler. Can you show your event handler and how the method gets called?

Comment: i changed now the code into async Task and awaited it in the ouside function. But there i had to use async void. But somehow this works. See above in my Solution, why I have to use there async void.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the `async void` is what is causing your problem. One of the [main problems with `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#avoid-async-void) is that calling code cannot know when the method completes. In this particular case, this means that the code cannot know when it's safe to dispose `_eventService`.

One option is to remove `async void`. If that's not feasible, then you will have to track yourself when it is safe to dispose `_eventService`, e.g., with a reference counted disposable.

Comment: Your post about `main problem with async void` helped, but I still strungling, why it worked with my Solution. The Problem for me is still that, the timer i used in a Hosted Service dont accept any async methods, but i used in my DoWork a method, that is using Async. Probably there is a more beautiful way, but i still don't know how because I'm a beginner with async.